# Is there a way to import Custom Object data from csv file using the Marketo REST API?

Tags: java, rest, csv, marketo, custom-object

I'm creating a new application to regularly import custom object data to Marketo. In my code I am using the REST sample for importing leads that can be found [here](https://github.com/Marketo/REST-Sample-Code/blob/master/java/LeadDatabase/BulkLeads/ImportLeads.java). That works just fine.
But how to import custom object data in the same way - from a csv file?

I have found the [SyncCustomObjects](https://github.com/Marketo/REST-Sample-Code/blob/master/java/LeadDatabase/CustomObjects/SyncCustomObjects.java) class but it is not using a csv file and I am confused. The Marketo web interface provides a way to import a csv file with custom object records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Marketo Bulk API.
/bulk/v1/customobjects/{apiName}/import.json

This imports a file containing data records into the target instance. Required Permissions: Read-Write Custom Object

More information is at,
http://developers.marketo.com/rest-api/endpoint-reference/lead-database-endpoint-reference/#!/Bulk_CustomObjects/importCustomObjectUsingPOST

Hope this helps

Rajesh Talele